# Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons':'AppIcon29x29' error

Tags: icons, xcode5, plist

I am attempting to upload my application to the app store but while trying to validate it I keep getting this error. So far I have no clue what is causing it.
Here are my icons, they look like they are working:
[image: Here are my icons, they look like they are working]
here is my plist
[image: Here is my plist]
Showing I do have Assets catalogue On
[image: Showing I do have Assets catalogue On]
Names of the Icons
[image: Names of the Icons]

Any clues? thanks in advance!

Comment: try to delete image, and re-add in your "image folder" of the project, and not directly in AppIcon

Comment: Nope, still the same, but thanks for helping.

Comment: Hey, did you ever get this working? Tell me how, I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I've been dealing with this problem for a week now. I've tried: renaming images; making sure none were transparencies, and are the right sizes; deleting AppIcon several times building and cleaning project over and over. Also, anything relating to CFBundleIcon has been removed from info.plist. I found this link that might help but, and since I'm very new to ios dev, not sure what to make of it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46109835/app-icons-not-included-in-build-from-xcode. I'm using xcode 11.5

Answer (score 0):

Check that the target membership for the asset catalog is correct.  This seems to be a common issue.

Also since you're using the asset catalog, you dont need the CFBundleIcon* property in the info.plist anymore since the build will actually compile the values into the compiled info.plist.