# App Icons not included in build from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I can't see iOS AppIcon when installing the build from the latest Xcode Beta. What could be the possible error?

I have included the required icon sizes including 1024x1024.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48209761/391605  It seems like Apple has quietly (and annoyingly) added extra icon requirements for iPads.

Comment: Try to ensure there is a "Contents.json" in each of image assets folder, which lists all assets and the device type they are mapped to.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are not alone.

In my project, I found that a previous AppIcon resource that was working fine no longer resulted in an app icon being rendered. A range of experimentation found the following:

- An AppIcon resource copied in from another project where the AppIcon worked, resulted in the AppIcon working in this project, suggesting there was something wrong with the specific original AppIcon resource that wasn't working.
- Copying the image files from the non-working to the working AppIcon asset resulted in the working one now failing also.
- Creating a new AppIcon resource, and inserting the original app icon images likewise led to a blank app icon.

Combined together, the points to this stage suggested perhaps there was something wrong with the image files themselves. I therefore tried various steps to resolve this:

- Re-exporting all the icon sizes with my usual pre-processing app Prepo. Ensured that my source image did not contain transparency. Inserting those re-created icon images still resulted in a blank app icon.
- Re-creating all the icon sizes with a different process, via Sketch, and inserting those icon images into the same AppIcon resource resulted in the app icon working.
- Creating a new AppIcon resource, and inserting the Sketch-created images resulted in the app icon still working.

All of the above suggests that there is something in Xcode 9 which rejects or fails to use previously working app icon images, and that some processes to create app icons that previously were fine produce images that Xcode 9 cannot use. Perhaps there is something within the png specification which is a valid png, but not an acceptable app icon to Xcode 9. The most obvious thought is that app icons with transparency might be rejected, but I do not believe the icon images I was using contained transparency and I tried to eliminate this in my testing above.

---

A completely separate cause that has been reported for some users is related to CocoaPods integration. See discussion with possible temporary fix [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7003) and a [pull request that has been created for Cocoapods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/7020) that theoretically addresses this issue. I say theoretically addresses because I've tried implementing both of these solutions, and neither of them resolved the issue on the project where I've encountered it.

Comment: This makes absolutly no sense to me, one of my projects is working and the other is not

Comment: I also tried removing the alpha channel from my icons and it still didn't work. I'm definitely in agreement that it is something in certain PNGs that they're now rejecting.

Comment: Deleting the key "CFBundleIcons~ipad" from .plist file worked for my build, while the others didn't. Check out the complete solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47597386/6346864

Answer (score 22):

For clarity, make sure that the color profile is set to: **sRGB IEC61966-2.1**. My icons had no color profile before I stumbled across this issue.

*I'm sure other color profiles must work but I haven't done the testing to be sure.*

This can be done in preview by:

1. Tools → Assign Profile

[image: Assign Profile1]

2. Select **sRGB IEC61966-2.1**

[image: Assign Profile2]

When you do a Get Info on the icons it should now say the correct Color Profile.

[image: Example of working / non working Get Info on two images]

Comment: unfortunatly this doesn't to work for everyone, thanks anyway mate you gave me hope

Comment: I had to remove the Alpha Channel to get this to work. (To do this open the icon in Preview, export, untick Alpha channel and save as PNG).

Comment: Awesome! After several days of trying, this solution works for me.

Comment: Deleting the key "CFBundleIcons~ipad" from .plist file worked for my build, while the others didn't. Check out the complete solution here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47597386/6346864)

Comment: I don't have any pod files but still my app icons are not showing. Even my icons are not transparent. This trick solved it.

Answer (score 17):

After trying various solutions like **"Asigning color profile (sRGB IEC61966-2.1) to icons"** and **"CocoaPods solution"** stated above, or **"Changing App Icon Source name to different asset name in proect setting"**,
I found one very basic solution as follow:

1. Clear your project
2. Clear derived data at (**~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/**)
3. Go to **"Project -> Build Phase"**
4. Find **"Copy Bundle Resources"** and drag it as the last item of the list
5. Uninstall application if it is already there, and run project

Find screenshot for better understanding.

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Note: You can check, what is creating problem for app-icon in your project by simply changing position of "Copy Bundle Resources" to upward direction.

Comment: I found a similar fix: the Copy Bundle Resources list did not include the `images.xcassets` file. Adding the file to the list fixed the problem. I didn't need to reposition the Copy Bundle Resources list itself.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem with my App icons. They displayed on some devices but not on others. I looked further into the problem and found that not all of my icons had been flattened and all had an incorrect color space (Adobe RGB).  I flattened all icons and converted to SRGB color space, then replaced the existing icons. All icons show perfectly now.

Comment: I am using a Mac App from the AppStore called "Asset Catalog Creator" to create app icons. They worked until Xcode 9. Your comment was useful, I went an looked at my images and the Color Profile was "Adobe RGB", and I found that my original image used to create the assets was also "Adobe RGB", there is a settings preferences in the "Asset Catalog Creator" that was checked "[x] Keep original color profile", once I unchecked that checkbox, then ran the icon asset creator with the original image, the new images are created with sRGB color profile and now WORK OK! Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Another Simple Fix once discovered:

I had the same issue with XCode 9.0, a project that worked perfectly well under XCode 8 and iOS 10 suddenly loses it's icons (only on iPads) when I upgraded the solution.

Tore my hair out, did the sRGB thing, did the Transparency thing.

Turns out I still had the following empty entry in my targets info.plist file

CFBundleIcons~ipad

I'd long ago moved to specifying this in the target build settings.

The solution was to simpy remove this entry from the info.plist file (clicked the helpfull little "-" button. Rebuilt and tested and everything was perfect once more.

Comment: For me it was quite the opposite. Was supporting IOS 7 and needed to add the missing filename entry to the CFBundleIcons~IPad dictionary. When I removed the key it caused it to find none of the icons despite being referenced in the xcassets

Comment: For me, also the AppCategory entry could not be empty. Maybe this means, all entries must be filled with some value?

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** This needs to fire in the middle of `gym`, which I don't know how to do. Running the bug fix as soon as the archive appears in the folder will do the trick. If someone can help improve this, please let me know!

I ran into this problem using Fastlane, and I wrote a shell script that I run as a lane to solve the problem. The fix itself is code from user stubyte in this [thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86290).

Here is my script for `archive_fix.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# navigate to latest archive created
cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives
foo=$(ls -t | head -n1) && cd $foo
line=$(ls -t | head -n1) && cd "$line"

 # bug fix
find Products/ -name Info.plist -print0 | xargs -0n1 plutil -replace BuildMachineOSBuild -string 16A323
```

Inside my Fastfile, I ran:

```
sh("./archive_fix.sh")
```

Answer (score 2):

I spent a whole day wasting time on this. I checked my png files to ensure no transparency, to ensure correct RGB settings, I also changed the podfile as discussed [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7003). Nothing worked. The upgrade to Xcode 9/iOS 11 seemed to break/change something as icons were previously showing for me for the same app.

Anyway, what fixed it for me was to change the name of the iOS App Icon in the Assets.xcassets (Default = AppIcon), and to also change the 'Asset Catalog App Icon Set Name' in the Build Settings to align with the new name.

Strangly, after I got this to work, I updated all my images in AppIcon within Assets.xcassets and I got a blank image again! Repeated above steps and problem solved for second time.

Comment: Added another answer to this post. See my other updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem:**

***1. App icon not appearing on iOS 11 or Xcode 9.***

***2. App icon visible on iPhone but not in iPad.***

**Solution that worked for me:**

The issue seems to be with the build process for Xcode 9 and iOS 11. In the past, Apple has been using ~iPad extension to differentiate between the assets for iPhone and iPad.

The info.plist has a dictionary with the key “CFBundleIcons~ipad” which has no items (as it appears in Xcode 9), which is causing the bundle to GET the images from the info.plist file instead of images.xcassets, thus the app icon on Xcode 9 is not appearing.

*Deleting this key from .plist* file worked for my build, while the others did'nt.

[image: Deleting "CFBundleIcons~ipad" key from .plist]

Comment: This was the culprit.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: create a "Copy Bundle Resources" Build Phase

After a day and a half trying pretty much every solution on this and other threads, I found a very different fix that worked for me. Looking at app package within my build folder, I noticed that the App Icon png files were not being copied over into it. I created a blank app from scratch, added an app icon, and in that blank app it did copy the icon file over. So what gives?

The blank app had a "Copy bundle resources" build phase that copied the Assets.xcassets package over. Mine didn't. So I created one, added my Images.xcassets, and presto change-o, my archive got validated. NB I am pretty sure I never had that build phase before, yet I was able to submit a build just a month ago ...

Answer (score 2):

In my case none these solutions worked.

My icons were not being shown cause they were **NOT IN CORRECT SIZES**. Once I resize them correctly then my issue got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from gales_vasile: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86290

Worked for me.

It should be a bug in CocoaPods, as disccussed here https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7003
I had the same problem but I fixed it following the next steps:

1) Add this code to Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
    copy_pods_resources_path = "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-IconTest/Pods-IconTest-resources.sh"
    string_to_replace = '--compile "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}"'
    assets_compile_with_app_icon_arguments = '--compile "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}" --app-icon "${ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME}" --output-partial-info-plist "${BUILD_DIR}/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist"'
    text = File.read(copy_pods_resources_path)
    new_contents = text.gsub(string_to_replace, assets_compile_with_app_icon_arguments)
    File.open(copy_pods_resources_path, "w") {|file| file.puts new_contents }
end
```

2) Change copy_pods_resources_path for your app and run “pod update”.
This should fix your problem!

Answer (score 1):

This issue comes due to **CocoaPods** for iOS 11. After few research I found one solution:

```
 post_install do |installer|
     copy_pods_resources_path = "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-XXX/Pods-XXX-resources.sh"
     string_to_replace = '--compile "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}"'
     assets_compile_with_app_icon_arguments = '--compile "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}"
     --app-icon "${ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME}" --output-partial-info-plist "${BUILD_DIR}/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist"'
     text = File.read(copy_pods_resources_path)
     new_contents = text.gsub(string_to_replace, assets_compile_with_app_icon_arguments)
     File.open(copy_pods_resources_path, "w") {|file| file.puts new_contents } 
end
```

Just add above to podfile and in terminal, execute **pod install**.
But this above code have limitation. 
There may such conditions like we have multiple pod then we need to run in loop.

```
 post_install do |installer|
     installer.aggregate_targets.each do |target|
         copy_pods_resources_path = "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Fixr/Pods-Fixr-resources.sh"

         string_to_replace = '--compile "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}"'
         assets_compile_with_app_icon_arguments = '--compile "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}"
         --app-icon "${ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME}" --output-partial-info-plist "${BUILD_DIR}/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist"'
         text = File.read(copy_pods_resources_path)
         new_contents = text.gsub(string_to_replace, assets_compile_with_app_icon_arguments)
         File.open(copy_pods_resources_path, "w") {|file| file.puts new_contents }
     end
```

end

It works fine when there is multiple file.

Answer (score 0):

A easy Way to change the color Profile is using the Automator.
Make an Job every file and folder

[Screenshot Automator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZFZp.png)

And save it.
then you can mark all Icon Files in your asset and choose the Job. 
All Profiles for the Icons will be made:)

Answer (score 0):

1- Add this code to Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
    copy_pods_resources_path = "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-IconTest/Pods-IconTest-resources.sh"
    string_to_replace = '--compile "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}"'
    assets_compile_with_app_icon_arguments = '--compile "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}" --app-icon "${ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME}" --output-partial-info-plist "${BUILD_DIR}/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist"'
    text = File.read(copy_pods_resources_path)
    new_contents = text.gsub(string_to_replace, assets_compile_with_app_icon_arguments)
    File.open(copy_pods_resources_path, "w") {|file| file.puts new_contents }
end
```

2- pod install

note: make sure you replace this:
Pods-IconTest/Pods-IconTest-resources.sh

as IconTest is the name of your app

or you can get this path by searching for .sh: (check image)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Having an incorrect icon size in your icon set can cause the App Icon to not display @iOS11. After many days of investigating, I found this entry in my build log:

> Showing All Messages, Filtering for "icon". warning:
>   ApplicationIcons.appiconset/Icon-40@2x.png is 80x80 but should be
>   60x60.

Whilst this message was present, my app icon was always not displaying (i.e. would see the default iOS app logo). I corrected the problem icon file (swapping it with the correctly sized image), and now my App Icon always displays. For some reason, changing the 'Asset Catalog App Icon Set Name' corrected the issue as a once-off. Subsequent app builds would result in the default icon displaying again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case one of the Pods contained .xcasset. Removing it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the app icon started to show up correctly in Finder after I changed

```
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>AppIcon</string>
```

into

```
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>AppIcon.icns</string>
```

in the Info.plist. My XCode version is 8.3.3

Answer (score 0):

After trying a bunch of these solutions, this is what solved it for me:

> 1). Delete any .xcassets folders in any of my Pod folders

Then delete any references to those files in:

> 2). Pods > Target Support Files > Pods-YourApp-resources.sh

Lastely, under my App > Build Phases > Copy Pod Resources

> 3). Remove any references to the same .xcassets paths

Afterwards just to be safe I did a Clean, Clean build folder, and then deleted Derived Data. Closed Xcode and reopened, voila!

Hope this helps someone, it took me about half a day as well to iron this out...

Answer (score 0):

After some days of research I figured out the problem, im my case the culprit was xcode 10 beta that cause the missing app icon issue on ios 11.

I downgraded to xcode 9.4.1 and now the icon appear on ios 11 as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case

- Xcode 10.3
- macOS 10.14.5

I had a legacy project that used `.icns` instead of `.xcassets`.
The app insisted on using the old icon even after I ...

- deleted all icon files;
- removed all the references to icon files in the `Copy Bundle Resources` build phase;
- ensured that no old `.icns` files included in the output app bundle resources; in fact, there was absolutely no `.icns` file there!
- cleaned, deep cleaned project build folder, manually deleted `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` before rebuilding;
- added `Assets.xcassets` to the project and tested varies renaming of this bundle: `images`, `Images`, `Icons`, etc;
- created and imported icon-set images that are generated from `Icon Set Creator`; The icon-set works for an fresh empty macOS Cocoa project.

What worked for me was something among a few desperate trials:

- Changed the Bundle Identifier and made sure everything still builds: this involves lots of one-click fixes that Xcode suggests to the project metadata, such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45976427/987846 and regenerating `.entitlements`.
- Removed and re-added `CFBundleIconFIle` property to the target's Info.plist. Name it `AppIcon`.
- Set `App Icon` property in the target's `General` settings to use my  `.xcassets`.
- Experienced `.xcassets` generating another empty AppIcon called `AppIcon-2` behind my back, so manually deleted it from `.xcassets`, then reset the App Icon of the target to `AppIcon`.
- Readding `.xcassets` to the `Copy Bundle Resources` build phase.

After rebuilding, this time the correct `.icns` is copied over to the app bundle's resources folder.

Answer (score 0):

As [Andrew Dunkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2333941/andrew-duncan) commented on another suggested answer, my image assets were not included in the Copy Bundle Resources build phase. I spent longer than I probably should have looking for this solution so I hope I save someone else some time.

1. Go to **Project -> Build Phases**
2. Open [**Copy Bundle Resources**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOmfH.jpg) dropdown
3. Make sure your folder with your image assets are included in this phase. If not add it. (The name of my asset folder was **Assets.xcassets**)

Comment: some screenshot will help more

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had an asset file called "Images", I had to create an asset file called "Assets". And then create an AppIcon inside.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

[image: Step 4]

Answer (score 0):

I searched for an answer for hours as well. There appears to be a variety of problems that can cause a blank app icon showing on an iOS device. Based on my searching, I suspect XCode requires very specific parameters for images used as app icons, parameters that are predefined by a user's image creation/editing software that are relatively esoteric. XCode should probably be more lenient.

**My solution** was to change my image's *precision* from 16-bit integer, to 8-bit integer. That was it. I had updated my image creation/editing software, GIMP, and noticed the default precision for a new image had changed in an update.

I tried every other solution mentioned by other people, including but not limited to: changing color profile to SRGB, ensuring image sizes were correct, making changes to the info.plist file, ensuring image names correlated with the Contents.json file, rebuilding the app, and restarting my device. It's a frustrating problem. Hopefully this helps someone else.