# iOS App Icon Missing on iOS 11

Tags: ios, xamarin, ios11

I am developing an iOS app in Xamarin. After upgrading Visual Studio to 7.3.2, my app not showing app icon on iOS 11 OS. App icon getting displayed on iOS 10 and earlier.

I am adding app icon in xcassets, added key in info.plist. Also, seleted proper source in info.plist file. Don't know what is going wrong.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Remove app and install again.

Comment: @KKRocks Done this, but still icon not showing. Even, I tried with removing icon image asset, but still no luck.

Comment: This answer might be way off base, but I've been (reluctantly) using Xcode, and noticed that with iOS 11, there was no icon showed on my iPad anymore. Apple seems to have added a new type of "iOS App Icon" file, with extra icons just for iPads.  Perhaps Xamarin hasn't caught up with this change, or you need to try to recreate your iOS app in Xamarin ?   https://stackoverflow.com/a/48209761/391605

Answer (score 6):

For anyone that might have the similar problem. I opened my info.plist with notepad and edited the Asset path which was pointing to the Resources/... folder while my icons were directly in the root of the application. make sure the following path is correct.

```
<key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
<string>Media.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset</string>
```

Comment: Thanks! Note that this occurs on VS2017 when you let it generate the assets for you: the assets are placed in the root, the path points at Resources/. That's how it generates your data. What a bug!

Comment: This is literally the only thing that worked! Great job finding this bug!