# Missing Appicons for IOS App Store upload

Tags: ios, xcode

It says I am missing image sizes of 76x76, 167x167, and 152x152 but I put them in my assets folder, any fixes for this? 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Those yellow warning triangles are telling you that something isn't right. Click on them and fix the issue.  I use IconFly to automatically generate the icon set from a single image input.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46109835/app-icons-not-included-in-build-from-xcode) would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your images aren't the right size. Go to Preview -> Tools -> Adjust Size... according to Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Those icons with the yellow warning triangles are saying that those specific images do not correspond with the needed format. Verify those images are of the correct dimensions.

If you verify they are correct, try dragging the icons individually into their corresponding app icon box.

Hopefully this helps.